# MySQL Haversine formula query fails when I control what I SELECT and I have no idea why?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

This is my query and it works perfectly in Spring Boot

```
@Query(value = "SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( :lat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( :lng ) ) + sin( radians( :lat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM m6db.pos_location_data HAVING distance < :range", nativeQuery = true)
List<PosLocation> findLngAndLat(@Param("lng") String lng, @Param("lat") String lat, @Param("range") float range);
```

But if I control the SELECT is throws an error

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id,lng,lat, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( :lat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( :lng ) ) + sin( radians( :lat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM m6db.pos_location_data HAVING distance < :range", nativeQuery = true)
List<PosLocation> findLngAndLat(@Param("lng") String lng, @Param("lat") String lat, @Param("range") float range);
```

**error**

> "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
>
> "message": "could not execute query; SQL [SELECT id,lng,lat, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( ? ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( ? ) ) + sin( radians( ? ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM m6db.pos_location_data HAVING distance < ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query",

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `pos_location_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_address` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11969 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Could anyone tell me why targetting the SELECT throws the exception?

I just checked an example query in MySQL Workbench and it works so I'm even more confused it bugs out in Spring Boot Hibernate.

```
SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 51.507351 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( -0.127758 ) ) + sin( radians( 51.507351 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM m6db.pos_location_data HAVING distance < 2;
```

Comment: I tested the query on MySQL 5.6. 37 and it works without error. Are you sure your schema name is `m6db`?

Comment: Perhaps Hibernate is trying to "help" by telling you that the HAVING clause should be preceded by a GROUP BY clause? Your query is relying on non-standard SQL that is supported by MySQL, but doesn't necessarily pass standard SQL tests.

Comment: The schema name is m6db. 
I tested GROUP BY, fine in native SQL but hibernate says nope. `SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 51.507351 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( -0.127758 ) ) + sin( radians( 51.507351 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM m6db.pos_location_data where client_name = "Post Office" GROUP BY id, distance HAVING distance < 2;`

Comment: I have no more insight into why Hibernate is complaining about this syntax which clearly works against native MySQL. This is on Hibernate to give better error messages.

Comment: Yep, I'm scratching my head too. I'm trying to find that combination magic of words that asks the right question :)